# How to get a Go program to block forever

Tags: go

I am trying to get my Go program to block forever,  but nothing is working.

Here are some things I have tried:

```
package main

func main() {
    select{}
}
```

and

```
package main

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)
    <-ch
}
```

and

```
package main

import "sync"

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Each time I get the same error: `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

I thought I have done this before easily. Am I able to get the go program to block forever?

Comment: `for true { print(".") }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, the `main` goroutine blocks forever,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func forever() {
    for {
        fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    go forever()
    select {} // block forever
}
```

Output:

```
2017-08-05 02:50:10.138353286 +0000 UTC
2017-08-05 02:50:11.138504194 +0000 UTC
2017-08-05 02:50:12.138618149 +0000 UTC
2017-08-05 02:50:13.138753477 +0000 UTC
2017-08-05 02:50:14.13888856 +0000 UTC
2017-08-05 02:50:15.139027355 +0000 UTC
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Those methods would work if you spawned another goroutine (which was doing stuff other than blocking)

The immediate fix to your problem would be:

`time.Sleep(math.MaxInt64)`

which would sleep for ~300 years

Answer (score 1):

For the question "How to get a Go program to block forever" there's already answers that use a for loop or `time.Sleep`.

But I want to answer "How to get a Go program to block forever *with a channel never receives a value*".

```
package main

func main() {
    ch := make(chan bool)

    go func(c chan bool) {
        for {
        }
        c <- true // Because c never receives true,
    }(ch)

    <-ch // thus ch waits forever.
}
```

I think the sample code above can help to understand why and when a Go program will block by a channel.

Comment: Thank you!
One thing I noticed was that with your example it was using 99% CPU.
But if I put a `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)` in the `for` loop, then it doesn't use all that CPU.